# MongoDB: how to shuffle array and this new order be permanantly saved?

Tags: arrays, database, mongodb, nosql, shuffle

So suppose I have a document like:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   items: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee"...]
}
```

I would like to shuffle the items list **once**, with this order saved in the table - i.e. I don't want to call random or something for every query, since there are about 200,000 items in this array (not huge, but still, calling $rand every time I want to retrieve an item would be inefficient)

So I'm really looking for some kind of manual script that I can run once - it would then update this document, so it became something like:

```
{
   _id: 1,
   items: ["ddd", "bbb", "aaa", "eee", "ccc"...]
}
```

If anyone knows if this is possible, I'd appreciate it. Thanks

Otherwise, I'd probably fetch the data, shuffle it using another language, then save it back into Mongo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the better way to do this

> https://mongoplayground.net/p/4AH8buOXudQ

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$items"
    }
  },
  {
    $sample: {
      size: 100 //to shuffle values upto particular index 
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      item: {
        $push: "$items"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: Oh cool, that worked. And surprisingly fast too. I set the sample size to 200,000 and the operation completed it <1s. I guess it may not shuffle every element (some may get shuffled multiple times, others zero), but in my case, that didn't matter anyway. Just a heads up if anyone reads this. Of course, you could get around this by just setting the size to e.g. 5x the number of elements...then it's likely most items won't in their original position

Answer (score 1):

If you're Mongo version 5.2+ I would do this using an aggregation pipeline update with the new [$sortArray](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortArray/) operator and `$rand`.

Essentially we add a random value for each item, sort the array and then transform it back, You can run this update on demand whenever you want to reshuffle the array.

```
db.collection.updateMany(
{},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $sortArray: {
              input: {
                $map: {
                  input: "$items",
                  in: {
                    value: "$$this",
                    sortVal: {
                      $rand: {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              sortBy: {
                "sortVal": 1
              }
            }
          },
          in: "$$this.value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t7BXxhSwIip)

If you're on a lesser version, you can generate some kind of pseudo random sort using `$reduce` ( you can actually do a bubble sort as well but that n^2 performance on such a large array is not recommend ), here is an example of how to generate some sort of randomness:

The approach is to iterate over the items array with the `$reduce` operator, if the random generated value is less than 0.3 then we push the item to be in the start of the array, if that value is less than 0.6 we append it to the end of the new array and if that value is between 0.6 and 1 and push it in the middle of the array.
Obviously you can choose whatever random logic you want and add more switch cases, as mentioned even an actual sort is possible but at the cost of performance.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $addFields: {
      items: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $reduce: {
              input: {
                $map: {
                  input: "$items",
                  in: {
                    value: "$$this",
                    sortVal: {
                      $rand: {}
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                $switch: {
                  branches: [
                    {
                      case: {
                        $lt: [
                          "$$this.sortVal",
                          0.333
                        ]
                      },
                      then: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                          "$$value",
                          [
                            "$$this"
                          ]
                        ]
                      },
                      
                    },
                    {
                      case: {
                        $lt: [
                          "$$this.sortVal",
                          0.6666
                        ]
                      },
                      then: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                          [
                            "$$this"
                          ],
                          "$$value",
                          
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  default: {
                    $concatArrays: [
                      {
                        $slice: [
                          "$$value",
                          {
                            $round: {
                              $divide: [
                                {
                                  $size: "$$value"
                                },
                                2
                              ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      },
                      [
                        "$$this"
                      ],
                      {
                        $slice: [
                          "$$value",
                          {
                            $round: {
                              $divide: [
                                {
                                  $size: "$$value"
                                },
                                2
                              ]
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            $add: [
                              {
                                $size: "$$value"
                              },
                              1
                            ]
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          in: "$$this.value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JVNsmBaIAkL)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm on 5.0.13 (even though I just downloaded it yesterday), so the first approach didn't work. As for the 2nd approach, kind of works, though doesn't provide a very random distribution, as I think you mentioned - for example, this would be a typical pattern - "AA", "AC", "AD", "AE", "AG" etc. When I tried with 200,000 elements, unfortunately the command became unresponsive. @nodejs developer's solution works well - it shuffles the items well and is relatively fast (just 2s, for 200,000 elements...and since I only needed to run that once, that's no issue)

Comment: that solution is fine but does not update the db, if it is used for an update just remember it is not atomic.